# Virtual directory not able to access the in web.config of the web site - Intermittently

Tags: iis

Intermittently, a virtual directory under the its website is unable to access the web.config.  It's as if the virtual directory is not properly inheriting the web.config file from it's parent website. The issue is not reproducible all the time and when we get this issue all we need to do is recycle the app pool for the website and everything works fine.

Somewhere in the code (from the virtual directory) we are doing something like this :-

```
string MembershipProvierName =
(WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/membership") as MembershipSection).DefaultProvider;
```

and the web.config on the parent website :-

```
<system.web>
 <membership defaultProvider="SomeProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SomeProvider" enableSearchMethods="true" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" type="SomeRandomType" defaultUsername="aaa@bbb.com" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
 ...
</system.web>
```

and the exception :-

System.Web.HttpException, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a    Message :     Source : System.Web    Help link :     WebEventCode : 0    ErrorCode : -2147467259    Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal    TargetSite : System.String GetPhysicalPath(System.Web.VirtualPath)    Stack Trace :    at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)       at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)       at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()       at System.Web.HttpContext.GetSection(String sectionName)

This is happening in production environment and  not reproducible in any other environment. In prod also, this is quite intermittent. In prod the IIS version is most likely 6.0.3790.3959. By any chance anybody knows If this is an IIS issue?